# How can I get just the value of the information?

Tags: php, distance, google-distancematrix-api

I want to get only the value of the kilometres to save it in a new variable.

I also tried to access the array with index.

My code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/routesetting", name="api_routeset_set", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function getRouteAction(Request $request) {
    $distanceMatrix = new GoogleDistanceMatrix('AIzaSyBdAHFe4MsbIr417NlPioNhYW7as-adBa8');
    $distance = $distanceMatrix
        ->addOrigin('Van Bronckhorststraat 94, 5961SM Horst, The Netherlands')
        ->addDestination('Maistraße 10, 80337 München, Deutschland')
        ->setMode(GoogleDistanceMatrix::MODE_DRIVING)
        ->setLanguage('en-EN')
        ->setUnits(GoogleDistanceMatrix::UNITS_METRIC)
        ->setAvoid(GoogleDistanceMatrix::AVOID_FERRIES)
        ->sendRequest();


    return $this->json([
        'message' => $distance
    ]);
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "message": {
        "status": "OK",
        "responseObject": [],
        "originAddresses": [
            []
        ],
        "destinationAddresses": [
            []
        ],
        "rows": [
            {
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "status": "OK",
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "6 hours 48 mins",
                            "value": 24461
                        },
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "695 km",
                            "value": 695380
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Expected result:

> 695380

Comment: Why not parse whatever `$distance` contains? This looks like a pretty simple JSON string

Answer (score 0):

`$distance` here seems to be a PHP array (I've never worked with this Google API).

So just before calling `return $this->json(['message' => $distance]);` you should just get the value you want from the `$distance` variable.

Which seems to be `$distance['rows']['elements']['distance']['value']`.

So returning `$this->json(['message' => $distance['rows']['elements']['distance']['value']]);` seems to be your trick. ;)

Be careful I haven't done any content verification here (`isset()`).